# What is the idea behind Go package naming convention?

Tags: go, naming-conventions

I'm trying to understand the idea behind package naming convention in Go. Most packages are installed and imported as something like:

```
import "github.com/howeyc/fsnotify"
```

I get the idea that package names should be unique, but I don't see the point of using the website `github.com`. Why not just use `author/package`? Like:

```
import "howeyc/fsnotify"
```

That's not likely to ever collide. Or some other "shorter" strategy? Is it because it "just works" with `go get`? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: It is, for the most part, about namespacing your packages to allow you to utilise forks, and/or know where the additional packages come from (otherwise, without a central repo, it'd be a hard task!).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `howeyc/fsnotify` if you want to. When `github.com/howeyc/fsnotify` is used it's understood that the package is hosted on Github. Other repositories work as well.

The reason is it makes it easier to locate and install dependencies with `go get`. Otherwise you'd have to satisfy the dependencies manually. And since forking repos is quite common in the open-source world, you may have a modified version from the same author. So it helps to distinguish what your project depends on.

Answer (score 1):

> [Download and install packages and dependencies](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go get [-d] [-fix] [-u] [build flags] [packages]
> ```
>
> Get downloads and installs the packages named by the import paths,
>   along with their dependencies.
>
> When checking out or updating a package, get looks for a branch or
>   tag that matches the locally installed version of Go. The most
>   important rule is that if the local installation is running version
>   "go1", get searches for a branch or tag named "go1". If no such
>   version exists it retrieves the most recent version of the package.
>
> For more about specifying packages, see '`go help packages`'.
>
> For more about how 'go get' finds source code to download, see '`go help remote`'.

The import path supports the `go get` command. Paths denoting remote repositories begin with the path to the code. Run the `go help remote` command for details.